# printf function for my OS

Tags: c, printf

I am working on a small OS: https://github.com/MihaiPro/OS
I am trying to create a printf function, this is code:

```
void printf(const char *str, ...)
{
    va_list formats;
    va_start(formats, str);

    char c, after;

    int tempI;

    int len;

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(str); ++i) {
        c = str[i];

        if (c == '%') {
            after = str[++i];

            if (after == 'd') {
                tempI = va_arg(formats, int);
                len = intlen(tempI);

                for (int x = len - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
                    int a1 = pow(10, x);
                    int a2 = tempI / a1;
                    int a3 = tempI / (a1 * 10);
                    t_putchar(STDK, (char)(a2 - a3 * 10));
                }   
            } else if (after == 'f') {
                    t_putchar(STDK, 'X');
            } else if (after == 'c') {
                t_putchar(STDK, (char)va_arg(formats, int)); // working
            } else {
                t_putchar(STDK, '%');
                --i;
            }
        } else {
            t_putchar(STDK, c); 
        }
    }

    va_end(formats);
}
```

Now here you have some other functions used behind:

```
size_t strlen(const char* str)
{
    size_t ret = 0;
    while ( str[ret] != 0 )
        ret++;
    return ret;
}

int intlen(int i)
{
    int ret = 0, r = 0;
    while (i != 0) {
        r = i % 10;
        i = (i - r) / 10;
        ++ret;
    }
    return ret;
}

int pow(int i, int p)
{
    int temp = p;
    while (temp > 0) {
        i *= i;
        --temp;
    }
    return i;
}

void t_mvcurs(struct terminal *Konsole)
{
    size_t pos = Konsole->row * 80 + Konsole->column;
    outb(0x3D4, 14);
    outb(0x3D5, pos >> 8);
    outb(0x3D4, 15);
    outb(0x3D5, pos);
}
```

Now, some clarifications:

STDK is standard terminal structure, it store position of cursor and color of background and color of chars.

My problem is next: printf function can print chars variables, but can't print integers. My pseudocode for print a integer is:

If current char in str is '%', check if next char is 'd'.
If next char is 'd', i store value of current variable into tempI(for this I use stdarg).
After I obtain number len and get each digit and convert it to char and print it. I found how to get each digit on web. But code print a smipley face or other symbol anything, where I wrong?

For more code, look at my repo.

Comment: Please take a look at [`printf` man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html): It should have a return-type of `int`, so it can return the number of bytes written. BTW: You only want to scan through the format-string once, no need for `strlen()`.

Comment: _print a smipley [sic] face_, that means you are printing the digit as the number itself, instead of the ascii (or whatever) code for that number. In ascii, digit `N` has code `'0' + N`

Comment: BTW, don't call with standard names functions which do not behave exactly like the standard wants. So call your function `kprintf` or something else than `printf`

Comment: Bug in `intlen`: `%` should be `/` in `i = (i - r) % 10;`

Comment: As an aside, consider only directly implementing `vfprintf`, and making all the others small forwarders to it (`sprintf` and the like would use a mem-stream, see [`fmemopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html)). Though maybe that's already too complex...

Comment: I think `intlen(0)` returns 0, which is obviously not correct. Consider using `do ... while()`.

Comment: minor: rather than `for (int i = 0; i < (int)strlen(str); ++i) {`, use `for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(str); ++i) {`.

Comment: Your `pow` function is wrong (unless it's a special feature of your own OS). `pow(10,2)` returns 10⁴, not 10². You do a power-of-two on each successive result, thus you get `i^(p^2)` instead of `i^p`.